# Index out bounds of array when adding data into an array

Tags: c#, arrays

So I have some code which stores some data in an array. When new data comes in it is put in a new array item (The totalnumber of array items) then the total number of array items is added too ready for the next bit of data. But when I try to add data into the array, be it array[0] or whatever it throws array index out of bounds?

Declaration:

```
string[] TabMessages = { };
int TotalTabs = 0;
```

Using it:

```
DevComponents.DotNetBar.TabItem Tab = TabStrip.CreateTab(TabName);
Tab.Tooltip = id + "|" + TabIndex;
TabMessages[TotalTabs] = "";//index out of bounds of array
TabStrip.SelectedTab = Tab;
TotalTabs++;
```

Any help, this is really annoying me because it's throwing the error about the index being out of bounds of the array when I'm trying to create a new entry to the array...

Comment: Arrays need to be allocated with the size required. If you want a dynamic array try `List`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrays in C# are not dynamic - they are fixed size. Try using something list a `List<string>` and using the `Add` method to insert a new entry into it.

`TabMessages` is an array of 0 elements (that's how you declared it). As such, you won't be able to add (or set) any element on it - you'll get an index out of bounds exception every time.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks, Also thanks to everyone else that replied for helping :)

Answer (score 2):

Arrays are a static length.  You have defined an array of 0 length, then tried to access an element in the array that does not exist.  Either you have to create a large enough array to hold all of the values you intend to use, or use a non-static collection like `List<string>` instead of a static-sized one like `string[]`.

```
List<string> TabMessages = new List<string>();
TabMessages.Add("");
```

If you want something you can access by index, but don't want to supply all possible values, use a dictionary:

```
Dictionary<int, string> TabMessages = new Dictionary<int, string>();
TabMessages[TotalTabs] = "";
```

Answer (score 1):

This code:

```
string[] TabMessages = { };
```

is equivalent to:

```
string[] TabMessages = new string[0];
```

it means you created array which size 0. That is why you got this kind of exception. So you can use `List<string>` instead with dynamic size:

```
var TabMessages = new List<string>();
```

Then you can add the first item:

```
TabMessages.Add(string.Empty);
```

Or, create string array with fixed size depending on your business rule:

```
string[] TabMessages = new string[5];  // create string array with 5 elements
```

Answer (score 0):

Array's are defined as having a fixed size. Declaring `string[] TabMessages = {}` is the same as `string[0] Tabmessages;`

You can resize an array (but I think it is a moderately expensive process) - see http://www.dotnetperls.com/array-resize

Alternatively (and preferably), try using some type of List construct